# AWS EC2 Instance Launch Configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this on AWS. What I want to do is:

I want to launch an EC2 instance using my custom AMI but on launch make some custom configurations to the environment. I want to:

- Checkout some git repos.
- Create a few php files with content i specify in a folder in my docroot.
- Install composer on one of the repos.
- Modify the https.conf docroot to a specific folder.

Can this all be done in the launch configuration? What would be a best practice for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely what EC2's [user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) functionality is for.

You can provide a shell script that makes your required changes, or even better than that, have the system pull its intended configuration from your Configuration Management solution (Ansible, Salt, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, this is very helpful. One thing that is still unclear is how I can modify the DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" in the httpd.conf. Basically I want to checkout a repo into /var/www/html and then modify the apache https.conf to point to a new DocumentRoot.

Comment: You use whatever standard unix stream editor you want to make the change (sed, awk, etc.). This is where a configuration management system can shine - deploying templatized configuration files that are filled out uniquely on a per-system basis.